Series of mutually independent variables that are dependent on an auxiliary random variable
Suppose that $X_1, X_2, ... , X_n$ are mutually independent random variables. There is a random variable $C \sim U(-1,1)$, which all $X$s depend on. How can I construct such $X$s so that they are unconditionally independent with zero mean?

If you want an actual example then it is easier to construct the $X_i$ first and then create $C$ depending on them.
For example, you could have $X_i \sim N(0,1)$ independently and have $C=2\Phi^{-1}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i\right)-1$ where $\Phi^{-1}$ is the quantile function of a standard normal distribution.
In R, to get a matrix of $n$ columns and $k$ rows (a row for each set of observations of $X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_n$), you could use:
Xmat <- matrix(rnorm(n*k), ncol=n)
C <- 2 * pnorm(rowSums(Xmat) / sqrt(n))

It is possible to do this backwards, starting with $k$ values of $C$, but is more complicated as you have to condition each $X_j$ not only on $C$ but also on the previously observed $X$ values.
C <- runif(k, -1, 1)
Xmat <- matrix(nrow=k, ncol=n)
S <- sqrt(n) * qnorm((C+1)/2)
for (j in n:1){
  Xmat[,j] <- rnorm(k, S/j, sqrt(1-1/j))
  S <- S - Xmat[,j]
  }

Either way, you will get $C\sim U(-1,1)$ and a positive correlation between each $X_i$ and $C$, while keeping the $X_i$ unconditionally mutually independent.
Conditioned on $C=c\in (-1,1)$, the $X_i$ and $X_j$ are not independent; they each have a conditional variance of $\frac{n-1}{n}$ and a conditional covariance between them of $-\frac{1}{n}$ and so a conditional correlation between them of $-\frac{1}{n-1}$. Unconditionally, their variances are $1$ and their covariances and correlations are $0$.

@CagdasOzgenc Starting with the $X_i$, they are unconditionally mutually independent by construction.  It is possible to start with $C$ and then construct the $X_i$ and achieve this, though the construction (which I have added for this example) is more complicated and the proof of mutually independence (which I have not added) much more complicated.

@CagdasOzgenc Yes - for the second block of code. If you want to see what happens conditioned on a particular value of $C$ strictly between $-1$ and $+1$ say $0.2024$, you can replace the first line of that block, for example with C <- rep(0.2024, k)

@CagdasOzgenc You can set $k$ to any positive integer, but a larger number will give you a better view of the distributions despite simulation noise.  I could have looped from 1 to n but that would have made the following line more complicated and less intuitive to me, perhaps Xmat[,j] <- rnorm(k, S/(n+1-j), sqrt(1-1/(n+1-j))) as all the $X_j$ columns have the same distribution.

If you use C <- rep(-0.9, k) i.e. conditioning on $C=-0.9$, then each set of $X_i$s will add up to a fixed $-1.644854\sqrt{n}$ and this conditional constraint will make them negatively correlated, with correlation $-\frac{1}{n-1}$ and this becomes more obvious when $n=2$. They are mutually independent when $C$ is uniformly distributed on $(-1,1)$.

If you choose $C$ uniformly distributed on $(−1,1)$ (without looking at it) then the sum of the first half of the $X_i$s tells you nothing about the sum of the second half as they are each normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $\frac n2$ independently of each other.  If you do look at $C$ and take its value into account (i.e. condition on it) then they are dependent - indeed you can calculate the sum of the second half exactly from $C$ and the sum of the first half.

The best estimate you can make of $C$ from seeing the first half, is the one which corresponds to the second half having mean of $0$.  With that estimate of $C$ and the data from the first half, the process reverses itself and the best estimate for the second half is then that it has a expectation of $0$; ignoring the data from the first half and just using the estimate of $C$ will give you a less accurate (and biased) estimate for the second half.

Yes you are right. And evidenced by generating many Cs and witnessing that first half and second half sums shows no correlation. This was really illuminating to understand the difference between conditional and unconditional independence. It would be really nice if you explained why your approach achieves this property (without a proof just intuitively)

The unconditional independence comes from the first construction, where $C$ is related to the sum of the $X_i$s and their CDF of the sum and so each $X_i$ is not independent of $C$, and conditioned on $C$ they are not independent of each other. The second equivalent construction uses the sort of idea appearing in another question.

How is it possible that S is all zeros at the end of the iteration, we are deducting random numbers after all?

In the second construction, $S$ is the sum of the as yet undetermined $X_i$s.  When you have only one $(X_1)$ to determine then it must be $S$ (here as a normal distribution with mean $\frac S1=S$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{1-\frac11}=0$) and then the next $S$ is the old $S-X_1 =0$. This should make sense as once you have decided all the  $X_i$s, there is nothing left to sum so the final $S=0$.

If you want to draw an arbitrary number of $X_i$s then use the first construction, though note that the value of $C$ would then keep changing.   Your link to an impossibility is that the sum of independent non-constant random variables should be $0$, which is a very different question.

@CagdasOzgenc Yes: $S_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$ and for given $n$ you have $C$ is a strictly monotonic function of $S_n$.   So in the first construction you can draw more independent $X_i$ and then $n$ and $S$ and $C$ change.  In the second construction you need to know $n$ and $S$ and $C$ before you see any $X_i$, so this prevents you changing $n$.

Let $\{Y_i, i=1,2,\ldots, n\}$ be any finite collection of random variables for which
(i) $\{C\} \bigcup \{Y_i\}$ are independent and
(ii) $E[|Y_i|] \lt \infty$ for all $i.$
For $i=1, 2, \ldots,$ let $b_i:[0,1)\to \{0,1\}$ be the $i^\text{th}$ bit in the binary expansion of its argument (choosing, say, $b_i(x) = 0$ when there is more than one possible expansion, so that this is well-defined).
Define $B_i = 2*b_i(|C|) - 1$ and notice that the $B_i$ are iid Rademacher variables (their values are $\pm1$ with equal probability).
The collection $X_i = B_iY_i$ does the trick:

The $X_i$ are independent because they are functions of the independent variables $(B_i, Y_i).$

Therefore $E[X_i] = E[B_iY_i] = E[B_i]E[Y_i] = (0)E[Y_i] = 0$ because $E[Y_i]$ is finite.


Here, to show how $C$ controls the distribution, is an illustration of a thousand realizations of $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$ using this method, starting from distributions named in the plot:

This is the R code to produce such illustrations:
to.binary <- Vectorize(function(u, ndigits = 52) {
  bases <- 2 ^ seq_len(ndigits)
  2 * c(floor((bases * u) %% 2)) - 1 # Converts 0 and 1 to -1 and 1, resp.
}, "u")
#
# Simulate `Y` and `C` then create `X` from them.
#
n.sim <- 1e3
Y <- list(Normal = rnorm, Uniform = runif, Exponential = rexp) # The RNGs
set.seed(17)
Y.realized <- sapply(Y, \(f) f(n.sim))
C <- runif(n.sim, -1, 1)
#
# Here's the algorithm:
#
B <- t(to.binary(C, length(Y)))
X.realized <- Y.realized * B
#
# Plot the results.
#
colnames(X.realized) <- names(Y)
pairs(cbind(X.realized, C), col = "#00000040")


you kind of drew a binary digit in random for each X and then used them to construct C by putting them side by side. right? in the reverse order of course by first drawing the C.

That sounds about right, but in reverse: The random drawing was determined by $C,$ which for this purposes is considered just to represent the first $n$ binary digits of its absolute value.  Schematically, we can express $|C|$ in binary as $b_1(|C|)b_2(|C|)\cdots b_n(|C|)$ where "$$" represents everything after the $n^\text{th}$ digit.

How would you attack the problem if you didn’t know n beforehand?

You don't need to know $n,$ because $C$ furnishes a (countably) infinite sequence of iid variables $B1,B2,\ldots.$

FWIW, I found a nicer method that doesn't produce so many zeros and illustrated it.

Thanks for the solution. However if we are encoding things, you could simply draw n random values and concatenate the first say 32 bit representation of each number and make a giant 32*n bit C value. One can create an encoder decoder by splitting C back to its components. Yes it doesn't use basic arithmetic but any Turing complete machinery can be used. It will have almost perfect accuracy.

The way your question is framed makes those considerations beside the point, so--although I agree with what you write--I am unsure what your point is.  What matters from the perspective of random variables is that the functions involved in creating the $X_i$ from the $Y_i$ be measurable.  Since they are simple functions (that is, locally constant measurable ones), that's not an issue.
